# How can I retrieve the ID of an email that was sent

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, c#

The results from an ET_SentTracking call don't appear to mention what the email ID was that was sent, how do I get that data using the Fuel SDK in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are retrieving the ET_SentEvent, it has a property for SendID.  This SendID can be used in a filter when retrieving the ET_Send object which would have the ID of the email that was sent.

Example ET_Send.Get():
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-CSharp/blob/Dot9/objsamples/Sample_Send.cs

Just change the filter to where 111111 is the SendID you get from SentEvent.

```
s.SearchFilter = new SimpleFilterPart() { Property = "ID", SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals, Value = new Value[] { 111111 } };
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't even see the ET_Send object in the Fuel SDK documentation.